# Bing Maps Query API, query by address instead of lat/long doesn't seem to work

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

Based on [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585133.aspx), I should be able to construct the query url with an address string inside the spatialFilter paramater. It works when I pass in the longitude/latitude, but I need to be able to pass in an address, a zip code, a city, or a state. An end user will be making a query for nearby locations of this custom datasource, they won't be searching geo-coordinates in the search box. Whenever I pass in a string other than lat/long, I receive a 400 BadRequest response: "Latitude values must be between -90.0 and 90.0 degrees."

Here is what my request url looks like:

```
https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/myId/myDataSource/myEntity?spatialFilter=nearby(ADDRESS_STRING,1000)&$format=json&$top=10&key=myKey&jsonp=callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have single quotes on either side of your address string. For example:

```
http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/20181f26d9e94c81acdf9496133d4f23/FourthCoffeeSample/FourthCoffeeShops?spatialFilter=nearby('Paris',100)&key=YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY
```

If your address has a single quote in it, then you have to escape it the OData way which consists of putting two single quotes together. For example `"o''clock"`

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was missing. I didn't realize I wasn't escaping quotes around the address string. I have a side question: My datasource has a total of 25 records. My results display fine, but is it possible to have all 25 records display according to distance from the address in the spatial filter? Instead of showing 2, 3, 8, etc results. I can think of a hack way to accomplish this but want to know if its an option before I start out with it

Comment: When using the nearby filter I believe it orders by distance by default. You can add this to the query to have the distance to each location added to the response: &$select=*,__Distance    

You can also specify that you want the results ordered by distance by adding this to the query: $orderby=__Distance But this should already be happening.

Comment: It does order by distance by default, but the max distance is 1000km. I have 25 locations total and need for all 25 to show, not just a few that are within the radius of 1000km of the search.

Comment: If you only have 25 locations, and you want to load all of them, then a nearby search isn't recommended. Instead you can do a bounding box using the whole globe or a property search and pass in a filter that all rows would match. Here is an example that uses the bounding box approach: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#sdsChoroplethMap+JS If you then want the distance to each location, the bounding box query will return a distance based on the center of the bounding box, which likely isn't what you want. You can calculate distance using the spatial math getDistanceTo function

Comment: Here is documentation for the spatial math library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750541.aspx and here is a link to a code sample that implements the getDistanceTo function: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#distanceBetweenTwoLocations+JS

Comment: thanks, this looks like what i need. ill investigate.